# How to use Setter for a Provider Class in Another Provider Class with flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a `General Provider` which is called on the start of the app.

it `fetches` some data via API. Normally I would keep it to that Provider for flutter but as the app is growing I think its better to separate the logic for all.

This first API also brings in the `user` data. Now I also have a `UserProvider` in the app. I created the below for it.

```
class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  UserModel _user;
  UserProvider(this._user);

  set setUser(user){
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }  
  
  UserModel get getUser => _user;
}
```

No error here but question is how to call this `setter` in `GeneralProvider` class?

The way I know is as below:

1. `UserProvider(UserModel(your_data));`
2. `Provider.of(context).setUser(UserModel(your_data));

First one works for me. and second one don't in the `provider part`.

Real issue with using `first way`:

---

In my `main.dart` where all the providers are provided, I need to do it like this.

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
  value: UserProvider(UserModel(your_data),
),
```

What I preferred is updating the `UserProvider` when the `general api` is called for `base data`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was this setter in UserProvider class:

```
  void setUser(User s) {
    _user = s;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

wrap your widget with:

```
 return Consumer<UserProvider>(builder: (_,provider,__){
   return WhateverYouWantToBuild(
   ...
   ),
});
```

and then calling it with:

```
provider.setUser(newValue!);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way:

`Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).setUser = your_parameter_here;`

Probably you already found the solution, if not this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updating this answer to newest version

```
context.watch<T>() // makes the widget listen to changes on T
context.read<T>() // returns T without listening to it
```

So here:

```
context.read<UserProvider>().setUser(NEW_USER);
```

Source: https://pub.dev/packages/provider#reading-a-value